# Obtain date and hour as new column from datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have the following column in a pandas data frame which has been imported from a CSV file. I wwant to add two columns contains the hour and the correspond day of the week.

input:

```
+-------------------+
|        date       |
+-------------------+
|2018/08/26  7:30:26|
+-------------------+
|2018/05/12  8:10:26|
+-------------------+
|2018/11/16 14:36:26|
+-------------------+
|2018/12/06 17:40:26|
+-------------------+
```

Output must be:

```
+-------------------+----------+------+
|    date-time      |  date    | hour |
+-------------------+----------+------+
|2018/08/26  7:30:26|2018/08/26| 7    |
+-------------------+----------+------+
|2018/05/12  8:10:26|2018/05/12| 8    |
+-------------------+----------+------+
|2018/11/16 14:36:26|2018/11/16|14    |
+-------------------+----------+------+
|2018/12/06 17:40:26|2018/12/06|17    |
+-------------------+----------+------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) accessor to obtain the `date` and `hour` from the datetime values:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.rename(columns = {'date':'datetime'})
df.assign(date = df.date.dt.date, hour = df.date.dt.hour)

         datetime        date       hour
0 2018-08-26 07:30:26  2018-08-26     7
1 2018-05-12 08:10:26  2018-05-12     8
2 2018-11-16 14:36:26  2018-11-16    14
3 2018-12-06 17:40:26  2018-12-06    17
```